# std::function signature pointer vs pointer reference = no difference?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c++11

Here is code example:

```
 #include <string>
 #include <functional>

 struct Foo {};
 typedef bool func_type(Foo *&, const std::string&);
 typedef std::function<bool(Foo*&, const std::string&)> FunctionalType;

 bool f(Foo *, const std::string&)
 {
 }

 int main()
 {
 #if 1
   func_type *func;
   func = f;
 #else
   FunctionalType f2;
   f2 = f;
#endif
}
```

As you see, I have declared function type with "reference to pointer" as the first argument `Foo *&`, and I expect that function with just "pointer" as the first argument `Foo *` cannot be assigned to a variable of this type.

The `#if 1` region fails to compile (as I expect); however, the alternative did not emit any errors:

```
FunctionalType f2;
f2 = f;
```

1. Why does it compile without error (with at least gcc 5.2 and clang 3.7)?
2. How it can be fixed, so that `std::function<Params>` does not accept `f` for conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::function` is a type-erasing container of invokable things.

It will store an instance of any C++ type that can be copied, destroyed and invoked with a "compatible" signature.

In this case, the signature is `bool(Foo*&, const std::string&)`.

The core idea is that when `Args...` in the `R(Args...)` part of the `std::function` type is `Foo*&`, `const std::string&`, those arguments *can be passed* to a function expecting `Foo*` and `const std::string&`.

`std::function` works based on *compatibility*, not exact matching of signatures.

If you really, really need to ban things that do not take references:

```
template<class T>
struct reference_only {
  T& t;
  operator T&(){ return t; }
  operator T()=delete;
  reference_only(T& tin):t(tin){}
};
```

then use:

```
typedef std::function<void(reference_only<Foo*>)> FunctionalType;
```

which doesn't like being converted to a value-type, but accepts being converted to a reference type (of type `Foo*&` in this case).

[Live example compiling](https://ideone.com/UQ6521), [live example not compiling](https://ideone.com/FkhrDQ).

Answer (score 4):

`std::function<R(Ts...)>` is defined as a type whose objects can represent any function that can be called with arguments `Ts...` and whose return value is convertible to `R`.

Since your function `f` can be called with an lvalue of type `T*` as the first argument (which is the requirement that your `Foo *&` imposes), it is a valid function to be stored in your `std::function`.

There is no way to suppress this behavior that I know of.

Comment: I mark another answer as answer, because of it provides some workaround for (2).